# Error in aray_diff function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using the following code:

```
$ab=array([0]=>5312,[1]=>26136]);
$abc=array();
$res=array_diff($ab,$abc);
```

If array $abc is not empty in that case it is working fine.

In this case I want the all the element that is in array `$ab` not in the `$abc` but it is showing the empty result. I also tried `array_diff_assoc()` function but it is showing same output. Please let me know how can I do it?

Comment: What's the problem? With correct syntax, I get both elements from `$ab` in the output `$res`.

Comment: The edit still isn't valid php. `$ab = array(0=>5312,1=>26136);`  No `[]` in the array def...

Comment: array $ab and $abc are dynamic. These are showing the output like this Array([0]=>46327)

Comment: PHP arrays are formed with either $ab[0] = 5312, $ab[1] = 26136, etc. or using the notation Michael pointed out ($ab = array(0=>5312, 1=>26136)). You seem to be mixing the syntax's and I don't think that is a legal PHP statement.

Comment: Yes - that is `print_r()` style output, which is not valid PHP. If that is your real code, it is a parse error.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your actual code, then the problem is you are likely getting an error on the first line as `array([0]=>5312,[1]=>26136])` is not valid syntax.  It should be `array(0=>5312,1=>26136)`.

Having `display_errors` on in your dev environment and have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` set would show this immediately.

Comment: That's not valid either. In an array definition, the keys are not bracketed in `[]`.  `$ab = array(5312,26136);` or `$ab = array(0=>5312,1=>26136);`

Comment: sorry typing mistake.now I have corrected you can see the problem. array $ab and $abc are dynamic. These are showing the output like this Array([0]=>46327)

Comment: Ahh yes of course.  very stupdi of me to not even notice that.  Was so focused on the missing `>`.  Will update my answer.